# Need help simplifying my php table

Tags: php, mysql, simplification

I am relatively new to php and have a feeling that I am going the long way round when displaying data from mysql.

I have a table a I want to show a few fields from my database.

How would I achieve this without having to echo every bit of the table???

Here is the code:

```
     <?php
$query1 = mysql_send("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, user, country FROM customers WHERE id='".$_COOKIE['custid']."'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1))

{

      echo     ' <table id="account_table" style="width:550px; border:none; ">
              <tr>
                <td width="155">Contact Name</td>';
      echo          '<td width="335">';

    echo $row['firstname'] ;
    echo '&nbsp;';
    echo $row['lastname'];

    echo '</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Email Address</td>
          <td>';
   echo $row['email'];

  echo '  </td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>' ;

    echo $row['user'];

    echo '</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td>';

    echo $row['country'];

    echo '</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Time Zone</td>
                <td>GMT+1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Activated</td>
                <td>16 Dec 2009</td>
              </tr>
            </table>';

            }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch all data into an array first and then iterate over that array. There is no need to echo all that HTML with PHP.

At the **top of your file**, you should do all the **processing** (i.e. getting, validating data) and in the **remainder** you just write **plain HTML**, only printing the values with PHP.

This already gives you a certain degree of separation. Others mention template engines (Smarty, etc.). I don't think that you really need that, because PHP itself is a template engine.
Just don't get tempted to do sophisticated stuff in your presentation ;)

Also the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) is very useful for using in combination with the presentation as it is imho much more readable.

---

I changed the table structure a bit, because you were not generation valid HTML (you create a lot tables with the same ID in your original code).
This just generates one table, with a row for each customer.

```
<?php
$customers = array();
$query1 = mysql_send("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, user, country FROM customers WHERE id='".$_COOKIE['custid']."'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $cusomters[] = $row;
}
?>

<table id="account_table" style="width:550px; border:none;">
    <tr>
       <th width="155">Contact Name</th>
       <th>Email Address</th>
       <th>Username</th>
       <th>Country</th>
       <th>Time Zone</th>
       <th>Activated</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach($customers as $customer): ?>
    <tr>           
        <td width="335">
             <?php echo $row['firstname'] ?>
             &nbsp;
             <?php echo $row['lastname'] ?>
        </td>          
        <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?> </td>     
        <td><?php echo $row['user'] ?></td>           
        <td><?php echo $row['country'] ?></td>
        <td>GMT+1</td>
        <td>16 Dec 2009</td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to look at some templating engine like [Smarty](http://smarty.net), that would allow you to separate presentation from php code.

Comment: +1, but I think Smarty is overkill. PHP can perfectly be used for templating. The ob_* family is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The basics seem right, although you will need to move the `<table>` tag out of the while loop, now you are creating a table for every entry and my guess is that that´s not what you want.

You also need to prepare your output for output to the browser with something like `htmlspecialchars($row[...])`. That way you avoid potential problems if the output contains html tags (javascript, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

First some advices, keep a window/tab open to the php manual. (ie, mysql_send() function doesn't exist).

Indent your code, and try to find a consistent convention to keep your code readable.

You're inserting your table markup into your `while` loop which is wrong. Your table should wrap your loop.

Using $_COOKIE as is to select from your database is **really** bad. Filter and sanitize your input before to use it in any query.

To avoid mixing data presentation and business logic, you can take a look to template engine.

Look at [19 Promising PHP Template Engines](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/) to find one, or take a look at the [wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_(web)).